# Event hub Handling receiver error for single event failure

Tags: azure-eventhub

is there a way for event hub listener to retry only the single failed event, or i have to fail the full batch
the listener gets a list of events and checkpoint will move pointer fwd. for full batch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to replay Events using EventProcessorHost. User is expected to handle the failures in user code (`ProcessEvents` code).

If there is a `poison event` in the system and the `EventProcessorHost` cannot proceed to execute and want to bail out - the only way to achieve this is to checkpoint until a known good Event and `unregister` the `EventProcessorHost` or `kill` the process.

You can control **until which exact event you want to checkpoint** using the [PartitionContext.Checkpoint(EventData)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitioncontext) API.